# Combining stores/loads of consecutive atomic variables

Tags: c++, c++11

Referring to a (slightly dated) [paper](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2007/n2338.html) by Hans Boehm, under "Atomic Operations". It mentions that the memory model (proposed at the time) would not prevent an optimizing compiler from combining a sequence of loads, or stores, on the same variable from being combined into a single load. His example is as follows (updated to hopefully correct current syntax):

Given

```
atomic<int> v;
```

The code

```
while( v.load( memory_order_acquire ) ) { ... }
```

Could be optimized to:

```
int a = v.load(memory_order_acquire);
while(a) { ... }
```

Obviously this would be bad, as he states. Now my question is, as the paper is a bit old, does the current C++0x memory model prevent this type of optimization, or is it still technically allowed?

My reading of the standard would seem to lean towards it being disallowed, but the use "acquire" semantics makes it less clear. For example if it were "seq_cst" the model seems to guarantee that the load must partake in a total ordering on the access and loading the value only once would thus seem to violate ordering (as it breaks the sequence happens before relationship).

For acquire I interpret 29.3.2 to mean that this optimization can not occur, since any "release" operation must be observed by the "acquire" operation. Doing only one acquire would seem not valid.

So my question is whether the current model (in the pending standard) would disallow this type of optimization? And if yes, then which part specifically forbids it?  If no, does using a `volatile` atomic solve the problem?

And for bonus, if the load operation has a "relaxed" ordering is the optimization then allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++0x standard attempts to outlaw this optimization.

The relevant words are from 29.3p13:

> Implementations should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads within a reasonable amount of time.

If the thread that is doing the load only ever issues one load instruction then this is violated, as if it misses the write the first time, it will never see it. It doesn't matter which memory ordering is used for the load, it is the same for both  `memory_order_seq_cst` and `memory_order_relaxed`.

However, the following optimization **is** allowed, unless there is something in the loop that forces an ordering:

```
while( v.load( memory_order_acquire ) ) {
    for(unsigned __temp=0;__temp<100;++__temp) {
        // original loop body goes here
    }
}
```

i.e. the compiler can generate code that executes the actual loads arbitrarily infrequently, provided it still executes them. This is even permitted for `memory_order_seq_cst` unless there are other `memory_order_seq_cst` operations in the loop, since this is equivalent to running 100 iterations between any memory accesses by other threads.

As an aside, the use of `memory_order_acquire` doesn't have the effect you describe --- it is not required to see release operations (other than by 29.3p13 quoted above), just that if it **does** see the release operation then it imposes visibility constraints on **other** accesses.

Comment: About the acquire semantics: Yes, I mis-worded that bit -- the release being visible establishes the sequenced relationship, but there is technically no guarantee I ever see it at all (except that such a compiler/cpu would quickly lose all market share).

Comment: About 29.3p13, I also read this bit and was tempted to think it makes this guarantee.  But because it uses the term *reasonable time* it has no value and could just be taken out of the standard. It's a meaningless term which means it can't be relied upon in low-latency situations. For example, in my current project, if this time is any more than 10s of nanoseconds there is no value whatsoever in the atomic operation (say compared to a lock).

Comment: Do you agree then, as I think n.m would, that making this atomic a `volatile` prevents the compiler from doing the optimization you have shown?

Comment: @edA: while _reasonable amount of time_ is not strongly defined, it pretty clearly cannot be infinite.  When talking about real-time constraints, the standard makes no claim at all about how fast things must run, but leaves things entirely up to the implementation.

Comment: Chris is right: the details of the timings are entirely a matter for Quality of Implementation. For one thing, the reading thread might not even be **scheduled** by the OS for several milliseconds. In a real-time system, I would expect that latencies would be short, and well-documented.

Comment: Okay. So on a quality implementation, which is suitable for real-time use, the use of `volatile` is likely redundant.

Comment: Yes. `volatile` is really for memory-mapped IO and signals, not multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Right from the very paper you're linking:

> Volatiles guarantee that the right number of memory operations are
>   performed.

The standard says essentially the same:

> Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the
>   rules of the abstract machine.

This has always been the case, since the very first C compiler by Dennis Ritchie I think. It has to be this way because memory mapped I/O registers won't work otherwise. To read two characters from your keyboard, you need to read the corresponding memory mapped register twice. If the compiler had a different idea about the number of reads it has to perform, that would be too bad!

Comment: Correct, but the question is *must* we put `volatile` on our `atomic` data to ensure it is read correctly? The inter-thread synchronization requirements seem to imply we might not. Yet on the same hand the atomics *do* have volatile qualified forms of their functions.

Comment: I think if you want the code `while(v.load(memory_order_acquire)){}` to most portably work with an absolute guarantee, then you have to use `volatile`. You need not use `volatile` in other cases, such as implementing the double-lock pattern, because there's a total order in the check-lock-check sequence and the compiler cannot reorder it to check-check-lock or whatever, even without volatile. Or so is my understanding anyway.